# Unable to add JIntellitype.dll to project through Maven

Tags: java, maven, dll, jintellitype

I'm working on a project and I need to use the JIntellitype library. I'm importing the project through Maven by putting the following code in my prj.iml

```
<orderEntry type="library" name="Maven:com.melloware:jintellitype:1.3.9" level="project" />
```

[The full project can be found here](https://github.com/melloware/jintellitype)

[The Maven URL is here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.melloware/jintellitype/1.3.9)

The problem is that I need the JIntellitype.dll to also be imported into my project for the library to work. The full project has the DLL, but the maven link does not.

I can download the DLL separately and import it into my project, however I would rather not do this because the rest of my team would also have to independently download the file and add it in.

Is there any way I can add a library or do something similar to add the JIntellitype.dll file into my project along with the Intellitype.jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That DLL isn't available in any public Maven repository that I know of.

How about:

1) Deploying it to your own private team instance of Nexus or Artifactory, so that you can reference it in your POM; or

2) Committing it to source control, and then use Maven plugins to copy the file to the correct directory, and register it in the `java.library.path` of your application.